# DELETE query in Postgres hangs indefinitely

Tags: database, postgresql

Currently I am trying to delete a row(s) in a particular database table **api_user**. Yet deleting hangs for seemingly infinite time *( currently been running for 1800 seconds as I've been looking for answers )*. The row in question had foreign key dependents, yet all of those dependents were deleted already, thats been verified.

I'm running all of my database introspection through Postico *( just another database GUI client )* So When i cancel the query i receive this error message.

```
ERROR: canceling statement due to user request
CONTEXT: SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."api_event" x WHERE $1::pg_catalog.text OPERATOR(pg_catalog.= ) "user_id"::pg_catalog.text FOR KEY SHARE OF x"
```

There are indexes that referenced the rows in this table. *api_event* is one table that had indexes on and foreign keys to this table. All of the dependent rows from api_event were deleted.

I've checked pg_stat_activity for any queries that could be running concurrently to no avail, and so I'm at a point where I'm not sure what the next question I should be asking is. Any direction would be great!

Running `EXPLAIN DELETE FROM api_user WHERE organization_id = '<replaced value>';` returns this to me:

`Delete on api_user  (cost=54.94..2903.50 rows=1874 width=6)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on api_user  (cost=54.94..2903.50 rows=1874 width=6)
        Recheck Cond: ((organization_id)::text = '<replaced value>'::text)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on api_user_organization_id  (cost=0.00..54.47 rows=1874 width=0)
              Index Cond: ((organization_id)::text = '<replaced value>'::text)`

**Lock Monitoring**

> Did you check if it's waiting for a lock? – a_horse_with_no_name

As per request I searched the locks on my database. I used this query:

```
 select t.relname,
        l.locktype,
        page,
        virtualtransaction,
        pid,
        mode,
        granted 
 from pg_locks l, 
      pg_stat_all_tables t 
 where l.relation=t.relid 
 order by relation asc;
```

The first return, my DELETE was not running, container 3 rows of locks from **pg_class**, **pg_index**, and **pg_namespace**.

The second return, my DELETE was running, contained 21 rows of locks. All of which were of a relname from a previously deleted set of rows that had either a foreign key or an index with this row.

**Road to Resolution**

Through more questions and [researching](http://www.databasesoup.com/2014/11/finding-foreign-keys-with-no-indexes.html), an interesting tidbit arose that not all foreign keys on child tables have **indexes**. After composing a query to see what foreign keys don't have indexes I noted that **api_event** did not have an index to its **api_user** foreign key. Now **api_event** is a humongous table.

Creating an index on **api_event** solved the issue.

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY user_id_to_events ON api_event(user_id);
```

Comment: How large is this table?  What does `EXPLAIN` show you?

Comment: Did you check if it's waiting for a lock?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i edited the original post!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added in results from checking the lock!

Comment: are you do it production level with zero tolerance for downtime ?

Comment: @DariusCalliet my suggestion for you is. block the pg_hba.conf, reload the database, restart the database, and delete cascade.

Comment: @AdrianHartanto I have an env that can support some downtime that I am running my tests on. Yet my production env cannot have downtime or at the very least a strict understanding of the downtime and its direct leading to the resolution.

Comment: @DariusCalliet the answer for the "Hang when Delete" is because the application still access that table you want to delete. make sure that table you want to delete no one access it. so PostgreSQL can delete the table gracefully.

Answer (score 3):

Create index is actually useful for slow delete query.
When you run DELETE query with "explain analyze delete from xx" ,and cancel it for too slow ,it will shows:

```
ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DELETE FROM ONLY "public"."AAAA" WHERE $1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "BBBB""
```

run `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY NAME_OF_INDEX ON AAAA(BBBB)`

will fix this problem

Comment: It's worth mentioning that, for me, the issue was an index in a table referencing the target table.  This obviously makes sense with FK constraints.  Just pay attention to the context output.  I also didn't need `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to get the output.  Maybe because this is a dev env - not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Not a very useful answer, but it might help someone. I experienced the same issue after doing excessive deletions on the table. I was experimenting with different delete queries and trying to find out which one is the fastest. I was also cancelling queries before they finished. I could not find the underlying reason, but what fixed the problem for me is

My DB was hosted on google cloud with backup support. So, I restored a backup from a few days ago, and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure (and not able to comment) but I think you are experiencing an heavy re-indexation or a vacuum after your deletion.